# How to convert a child state to parent state or vice versa dynamically based on screen width?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a kind of situation where I need to nest the child state when screen size is desktop and convert the child state to parent state when screen is mobile.

**Desktop**

```
<div ui-view="parent">
 <div ui-view="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Mobile**

```
<div ui-view="child"></div>
```

What is the best way to do that? 
I'm thinking of creating a separate state for desktop and mobile with same controller and template and navigate to the state based on screen width

Comment: ui-state router state .state("parent",{}) .state("child",{})

Comment: yea I can use media queries but it's time consuming, so I was just looking for a way if a single state can both act as a child and parent